# How does Node package manager decide which version to install?

Tags: npm

When I run `npm install @angular/cdk` without specifying a version, how does NPM decide which version to install? Does it look at other packages I have installed already and try to find compatible version, or does it simple get the highest available version?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like npm should default to the version that has been tagged as "latest" on the npm registry.

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-install

> `npm install [<@scope>/]<name>:`
>
> Do a @ install, where  is the "tag" config. (See
> config. The config's default value is latest.)
>
> In most cases, this will install the version of the modules tagged as
> latest on the npm registry.
>
> Example:
>
> `npm install sax`